# How to get normal Map to work using Direct X, in Pixel shader

Tags: directx

I have the tangents and the bitangents etc, I think I have the math correct up until the final stuff in the pixel shader.

I have been looking at tutorials but can't seem to get it to work in my own programme.

My normal map code looks like this so far:

```
   float3 normalMap = (nTex.Sample(mySampler, input.UV).rgb);


normalMap = (normalMap * 2) - 1.0f;

input.tangents = normalize(input.tangents - dot(input.tangents, input.normal) * input.normal);

float3 biTang = cross(input.normal, input.tangents);

float3x3 texSpace = float3x3(input.tangents, biTang, input.normal);

//float3 normalWW = float3(normalMap.r, normalMap.g, normalMap.b);

input.normal = normalize(mul(normalMap, texSpace));

float3 plDir = float3(pointLightDir.rgb);

//float final = saturate(dot(-plDir, input.normal));


//float4 finalW = saturate(float4(combined * final));

output.Color = color * combined;

output.Color+= saturate((dot(-plDir, input.normal)*combined)*color);


output.Color.a = 1;
```

I haven't named things in a good way yet.
"combined" is my phong shading, I have diffuse, specular and ambient added together. "color" is just the sampled diffuse texture.

The result is no different than if I only had the first texture. if I only use the normal map it's displayed so that works.

I'm in directx in c++.

Comment: Are you using object-space or tangent-space normal maps? You may find the code [here](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/blob/master/Src/Shaders/NormalMapEffect.fx) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/blob/master/Src/Shaders/Utilities.fxh) useful.

Comment: Try only this instead of adding: output.Color = saturate((dot(-plDir, input.normal)*combined)*color);

Comment: thanks for the replies, I am using tangent space normal maps, I have tried alot of combinations, that didn't work either.

Comment: I think you should do `mul(texSpace, normalMap)` instead of `mul(normalMap, textSpace)`.